# how to get a restricted subset of related records with extbase?

Tags: sql, typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

assuming I have these simplified data (`subrec` are IRRE-records to `records`):

```
record: 
   uid = 1
   title = record-1
   subrecs:
      * subrec:
           uid = 1
           title = subrec-1
      * subrec:
           uid = 2
           title = subrec-2
      * subrec:
           uid = 13
           title = subrec-13
record: 
   uid = 2
   title = record-2
   subrecs:
      * subrec:
           uid = 3
           title = subrec-3
      * subrec:
           uid = 12
           title = subrec-12
record: 
   uid = 3
   title = record-3
   subrecs:
      * subrec:
           uid = 11
           title = subrec-11
      * subrec:
           uid = 21
           title = subrec-21
```

now I want a selection of all records/subrecords where `subrec.uid < 10`. This should result in:

```
record: 
   uid = 1
   title = record-1
   subrecs:
      * subrec:
           uid = 1
           title = subrec-1
      * subrec:
           uid = 2
           title = subrec-2
record: 
   uid = 2
   title = record-2
   subrecs:
      * subrec:
           uid = 3
           title = subrec-3
```

if I use extbase functionality in the recordRepository with:

```php
public function findRestrictedRecords($limit) {
   $recordQuery = $this->createQuery();
   $recordQuery->matching($recordQuery->lessThan('subrecs.uid', $limit));
   return $recordQuery->execute();
}
```

I get all sub-records to the records which have sub-records which match the condition.
which is:

```
record: 
   uid = 1
   title = record-1
   subrecs:
      * subrec:
           uid = 1
           title = subrec-1
      * subrec:
           uid = 2
           title = subrec-2
      * subrec:
           uid = 13
           title = subrec-13
record: 
   uid = 2
   title = record-2
   subrecs:
      * subrec:
           uid = 3
           title = subrec-3
      * subrec:
           uid = 12
           title = subrec-12
```

As I want the query result to be shown and exported as CSV (with denormalized records) I need to add the same restriction-checks to the subrecords than the query itself.
I have more fields to the records and the restriction consists of multiple fields constraints. So the filtering on output is tedious.

final output should be:

```
"resord.uid","record.title","subrec.uid","subrec.title"
1,resord-1,1,subrec-1
1,record-1,2,subrec-2
2,record-2,3,subrec-3
```

How can this be simplified?

---

The **generated(!)** query by this code would be something like (I simplified my real structure and also simplified the real query, so it might have some errors)

```sql
SELECT `tx_myext_domain_model_record`.* 
  FROM `tx_myext_domain_model_record` `tx_myext_domain_model_record`
  LEFT JOIN `tx_myext_domain_model_subrec` `tx_myext_domain_model_subrec` 
      ON `tx_myext_domain_model_record`.`uid` = `tx_myext_domain_model_subrec`.`parent` 
WHERE (`tx_myext_domain_model_subrec`.`uid` < '10')
  AND (`tx_myext_domain_model_record`.`pid` = '2')
  AND (    (`tx_myext_domain_model_person`.`hidden` = 0) 
       AND (`tx_myext_domain_model_record`.`starttime` <= 1637841540) 
       AND (   (`tx_myext_domain_model_record`.`endtime` = 0) 
            OR (`tx_myext_domain_model_record`.`endtime` > 1637841540)) 
       AND tx_myext_domain_model_record.deleted=0) 
       AND (((`tx_myext_domain_model_subrec`.`hidden` = 0) 
            AND (`tx_myext_domain_model_subrec`.`starttime` <= 1637841540) 
            AND (   (`tx_myext_domain_model_subrec`.`endtime` = 0) 
                 OR (`tx_myext_domain_model_subrec`.`endtime` > 1637841540)) 
            AND tx_myext_domain_model_subrec.deleted=0) 
      OR (`tx_myext_domain_model_subrec`.`uid` IS NULL))
```

Comment: Show us your current SQL query attempt.

Comment: As the query is generated by that tiny piece of PHP I didn't included it first. Now I added it (and hope I simplified it correctly).